# SQL command not properly ended after the as statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create a view named PROJECT_FEMALE. From 3 different tables but sql gives me that error.

```
CREATE VIEW PROJECT_FEMALE 
AS
    SELECT e.Ssn, e.Fname, e.Lname, p.Pnumber, p.Pname, w.Hours
    FROM Employee AS e, Works_on AS w, Project AS p
    WHERE e.Ssn = w.Essn AND w.pno = p.Pnumber AND e.sex = 'F';
```

Error:

> [Code: 933, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
> [Script position: 103 - 105]

It points as statement after the `Employee` but I do not understand what is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Yeah, when I do that with 'Join' it works fine I think it is from syntax . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not support table aliases with `AS`, you can only use `AS` for column aliases; so, your code should be:

```
CREATE VIEW PROJECT_FEMALE
AS
   SELECT e.Ssn,
          e.Fname,
          e.Lname,
          p.Pnumber,
          p.Pname,
          w.Hours
     FROM Employeee, Works_on w, Project p
    WHERE e.Ssn = w.Essn AND w.pno = p.Pnumber AND e.sex = 'F';
```

or (better)

```
CREATE VIEW PROJECT_FEMALE
AS
   SELECT e.Ssn,
          e.Fname,
          e.Lname,
          p.Pnumber,
          p.Pname,
          w.Hours
     FROM Employee e
          INNER JOIN Works_on w ON (e.Ssn = w.Essn)
          INNER JOIN Project p ON (w.pno = p.Pnumber)
    WHERE e.sex = 'F';
```